# Where exactly does energy quantisation come in for light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, discrete

Planck quantised the energy of light in order to solve the black body radiation problem. However, I am confused as to exactly what he quantised. On one hand, I have seen that he quantised the energy of oscillators in the black body (source below).
[image]

[Source of photo](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys314/lectures/planck/planck.html)

However, the second version of the story I've heard is that it is simply that light energy is given off in discrete chunks (where every photon itself can have any value of energy it likes depending on frequency and is not quantised).

To me, the first idea doesn't make sense because $E=hf$ and as $f$ can be any real number that means the energy of each photon can be any real number. I would believe the second version, however I don't understand how this version of quantisation leads to reducing the number of high frequency waves emitted and thus solving the UV catastrophe. Could you please explain exactly how releasing energy in chunks (of arbitrary size themselves) means less will be released in the higher frequencies?

Comment: Light isn't quantised in the sense buried in your wording. The electromagnetic spectrum is a continuum, indeed. Is the energy of each chunk that is quantised, chunk that is emitted by an oscillator in the case of BB, or by whatever system having quantised levels like in optical electronic transition. *f* can be "any" number, but must be that number. Volume can be any number, but once you have standard bottles, then it comes as n times the volume of the bottle, as this analogy might helps many readers.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your two accounts boil down to the same. Can you clarify?

Comment: I could copy this for an answer to your last question http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html#c2 (second page)

Comment: Very similar question here: [Where is quantization used in deriving Planck's law?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453835/where-is-quantization-used-in-deriving-plancks-law)

Comment: $E=hf$ is the energy of _one photon_ with frequency $f$. The energy of _one photon_ can indeed be continuously varied by varying its frequency. The thing that's quantized is the number of photons of each frequency.  For any given frequency $f$, the energy of $N$ of that collection of photons is $E=Nhf$. The $N$ is quantized, not the $f$.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

First of all, $E=hf$ is the energy of a photon. Now, if you take two photons, the enegy is *twice* that. You cannot have $1.5E$, since it does not make sense to talk about $1.5$ photons. Also, you misunderstood "discrete chunks" which is actually *photons* themselves. The energy is absorbed or emitted as *photons*.

Obviously $hf$ could be any real number , but fractional values of $hf$ *cannot* exist. Only *integral multiples* are allowed. That is all.

[image]

If a body is heated (say a blackbody), it would radiate in all frequencies. This is common. What you would get if you used a detector to say apart the types of EM waves emitted, there would be a peak intensity at a certain frequency. There would be smaller intensities at all other frequencies.

Here, $E=hf$ is not used. Instead, the curve for the blackbody radiation law uses the following one for a plot $B(\lambda,T)$ against $ \lambda$.

$$B(\lambda, T)= \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5(e^{\frac{hc}{\lambda kT}}-1)}$$

This peak is not a constant for a specific body, but only at that specific *temperature*. If you vary the *temperature* around, you would get peaks at different frequencies.